# ExtJS - Lining up form elements in FormPanel column layout

Tags: forms, layout, extjs

I have a FormPanel with 3 columns. Each column is 33% of the FormPanel width. Looks something like this:

```
searchForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    frame: true,
    title: 'Search Criteria',
    labelAlign: 'left',
    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
    labelWidth: 85,
    width: 900,
    items: [{
        layout: 'column',
        items: [{ // column #1
            columnWidth: .33,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Banner ID',
                name: 'bannerID',
                anchor: '95%',
            },
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                fieldLabel: 'Advertiser',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                mode: 'local',
                emptyText: 'Advertiser',
                store: advertiserList,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name'
            })] // close items for first column
        }, {
            columnWidth: .33,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Banner Name',
                name: 'bannerName',
                anchor: '95%',
            },
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                fieldLabel: 'Art Type',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                mode: 'local',
                emptyText: 'Art Type',
                store: artTypesList,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name'
            })] // close items for second column
        }, {
            columnWidth: .33,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'hidden'
            },
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                fieldLabel: 'Art Size',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                mode: 'local',
                emptyText: 'Art Size',
                store: artSizeList,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name'
            })] // close items for third column
        }]
    }]
}); // close searchForm FormPanel
```

It displayed something that looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

Only problem is I want the "Art Size" field/label to be aligned on the same row as the "Advertiser" and "Art Type" fields. Is there any way to add a "blank" item, such that it forces the entry down to the correct row? Is there another approach to this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT:
This worked:**

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    fieldLabel: '&nbsp;',
    labelSeparator: ' ',  
}
```

Comment: You could try adding in a blank component. i.e. {xtype: 'component'} in front of the art size item.

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't work. Do I have to specify and parameters for it?

Comment: add your answer and mark it as accepted so other people can see it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: This worked:

```
           {
                xtype: 'component',
                fieldLabel: '&nbsp;',
                labelSeparator: ' ',  
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

by default empty  labels are hidden (the field is pushed to the left).
instead of putting '&nbsp ;' label ...

```
fieldLabel: '&nbsp;',
labelSeparator: ' ',
```

you can do it properly:

```
hideEmptyLabel : false
```

witch will align your filed component even if no label is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution will work but it is not the ExtJS(/HTML tables) way.

You are using a `column` layout so you can use `colspan: 2` on the banner name field which results in the same output.
You also can use rowspan to have your field cover two rows :)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above seems to have worked for me. I had to explicitly set the height of the empy cell.

```
xtype: 'label',
text: ' ',
flex:1,
height:22
```

Disappointing to say the least.

However this only works with **vBox** layout. If I use **anchor** layout then nothing works :(